# get rid of dup ? sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 create or replace function get_job_count
      (E_id in employees.employee_id%type)
    return number
    is
      job_nb_employee  number;    
      job_nb_history number;
      job_nb_total   number;
    begin
      select count(*)    
        into job_nb_employee
        from employees
        where employee_id = E_id;
      
    select count(*)        
        into job_nb_history
        from job_history
        where employee_id = E_id;
     
     
        
      job_nb_total := job_nb_history + job_nb_employee;   -- add the total job 
       
     if job_nb_total = 0  then                        --throw an error if ID is invalid
     raise_application_error(-20111,'Not Valid ID');
        END IF;
      return job_nb_total;
      
    end;
```

How can I treat dupplicated job_id in this function.

The goal is to count how many DIFFERENT JOB the employee has, if he switched to a different job and came back to his original job it count as 2 and not 3 right now I can only count all the job that he has.
Where should I start?

I use HR on oracle sql developper

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do everything you need on the SQL side. You only need a single top-level `select` query, selecting a count **distinct** of `job_id` from the union of the two tables. Then you also only need one local variable in the function.

Something like this:

```
create or replace function get_job_count
      (E_id in hr.employees.employee_id%type)
    return number
    is
      job_nb_total   number;
    begin
      select count(distinct job_id)    
        into job_nb_total
        from (
          select job_id
          from   hr.employees
          where employee_id = E_id
          union all
          select job_id
          from hr.job_history
          where employee_id = E_id);
     if job_nb_total = 0  then             --throw an error if ID is invalid
     raise_application_error(-20111,'Not Valid ID');
        END IF;
      return job_nb_total;
    end;
/
```